# struct typedef names that clash with stdlib

Tags: c, naming-conventions

I have an issue where one of my struct typedefs, `mode_t`, clashes with one in the `stdlib`

`mode_t` is already defined in `sys/types.h`

whats best practice in this instance? to rename my struct to something else or is there some other way to resolve the clash?

Comment: In C++, you can use namespace. Since this is not C++, I will not post this as answer.

Comment: Names that end with `_t` are reserved for additional type names.

Comment: @Jayesh: yes, but by which authority are they reserved?  Hint: it isn't the C standard.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler While using these names for your own purposes right now might not cause a problem, they do raise the possibility of conflict with future versions of the `C` or `POSIX` standards, so you should avoid these names.ISO C standard are reserved unconditionally; your program may not redefine these names.

Comment: ok - so you shouldn't use _t to denote struct typedef names in your own code?

Comment: @Hiett Under C convention (such as in the C standard library or POSIX), types declared with typedef end with '_t' (e.g., size_t, time_t). Such type names are reserved by POSIX for future extensions and should generally be avoided for user defined types.

Comment: @Jayesh: Right — the POSIX standard explicitly reserves names ending in `_t`; the section is [2.2 Compilation Environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02) and sub-section 2.2.2 The Name Space.

Comment: ok - so _t is a no-go - is there a generally accepted way to indicate something is a struct typedef? or maybe you just shouldn't use typedefs as it obscures the fact a struct is being used?

Comment: i may start my own _s convention.. or has some other standard already snapped this one up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Never** have your own structure name or variable name that ends in `_t`. Regard all such names as reserved by either the compiler or the standard library.

Although technically legal by the C standard, many platforms (e.g. POSIX) explicitly forbid it.

Your best option is to rename your structure.

Comment: is there a defacto typedef naming convention for C? I started off thinking it was to use a leading capital (bit like a class name) then I thought you used a trailing _t - is there another way?

Comment: The de facto typedef naming convention in C is all small letters, ending with `_t`. It has been like that forever, long before POSIX. It does not clash with anything in the C standard. POSIX might have made the really stupid decision to reserve it, but that's too bad for POSIX then.

Comment: i thought that was the case - maybe i can stick with all my _t's after all? looks like we have a split in opinion here. I just wanted to be sure that it wasn't bad practice to use this convention though

Comment: @bathsheba what naming convention (if any) do you use to denote a struct typedef?

Comment: @Heitt: I tend to use `typedef` CamelCase on an anonymous `struct` in order to inject it into the `typedef` namespace. I **never** use _Capital as using an underscore followed by a capital letter is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: I think there is also an argument not to use typedefs and explicitly type struct everywhere - i think i read that this is a linux src code convention

Comment: @Heitt: I would disagree. The `typedef` namespace is well-defined in the C standard.

Comment: @Bathsheba so your leading capital letter is the indicator that you are dealing with a struct

Comment: @Heitt: Yes, but it's personal choice. I use CamelCase for structs and camelCase for variables and functions.

Answer (score 2):

If the name conflicts in C program, then you need to rename your structure. In C++, you can use namespace.

Or if you want to use this name, then do not include `sys/types.h`.

Comment: problem I have is that including stdlib.h is pulling in sys/types.h, e.g. i am not explicitly including sys/types.h. I don't want to start modifying stdlib.h and I can't not use stdlib.h so I think my only option is to rename - makes me think namespaces are a sensible language feature

Answer (score 1):

If your program names clash with the library variable names, change the names in your program.